# NullReferenceException randomly occurs after publishing

Tags: umbraco

I've started work on an existing site for a client where they seem to be experiencing a weird bug: At random intervals, whenever a node is saved and published it causes every node to display a yellow error screen, as below:

[image]

The only way we've managed to fix the problem is by deleting the umbraco.config file in App_Data and then bumping the web.config so the application rebuilds. This fix will last until the next random save and publish where the 'fix' will need to be repeated.

Due to the size of the site and number of content editors this problem seems to be happening quite often and it's becoming a real nuisance to have to keep deleting config files.

FYI we heard the bug could be fixed by upgrading to the latest version ie. 6.1.6, which we've done, but this hasn't fixed the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it could be something that's instantiated on App Start and held in memory. Have you been able to verify that it's happening after a certain interval of inactivity, or based on some specific event? Perhaps something is causing it to be disposed and it's not being re-instantiated properly without a full recompile/republish? Sorry not much but hopefully it can help.

Comment: Turns out it's actually something to do with the PublishAt values that were placed on some of the nodes. It seems Umbraco has a service running that was trying to publish the nodes periodically but this was failing. I'm not quite sure why exactly but once I deleted all references of these nodes (including ones in the recycle bin) the error stopped

Comment: Good stuff, glad you found the issue!